In EPPlus is there a way to Imbed an image in a cell (or spanned cell)?
Is there a way in EPPlus to programatically insert and image into a cell? (If you run this code in VBA in a recent version of Excel) it will imbed the image and save the image in the sheet.
Overlayed vs Embedded Image
Sub InsertPictureInCell(cellAddress As String, filePath As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pic As Picture

   ' Set the worksheet where you want to insert the picture
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name

   ' Insert the picture
   Set pic = ws.Pictures.Insert(filePath)

   ' Position the picture over cells
   With pic
       .Top = ws.Range(cellAddress).Top
       .Left = ws.Range(cellAddress).Left
       .Placement = 1 ' xlMoveAndSize
   End With

   Set shp = ws.Shapes(pic.Name)

   Range(cellAddress).Select

   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(pic.Name)).Select
                   
   ws.Shapes(pic.Name).PlacePictureInCell
End Sub


Sub TestInsertPictureInCell()
    InsertPictureInCell "A1", "C:\Image.png"
End Sub

I tried a few examples but could only get an overlayed image not an imbedded image.
InsertPictureInCell / PlacePictureInCell

Try to use this code (I tested only in C#, but you can translate it to VB easily):
public static void InsertPictureInCell(string cellAddress , string filePath)
{
    FileInfo image = new FileInfo(filePath);                        // Image file info
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("your excel file full path");        // Excel file info
        
    // Starts using Excel Package
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {

        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial; // Non-commercial license
        ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];  // Sets ws to Sheet1 
                           
        ExcelPicture pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("name", image);   // Excel picture object
        ExcelRange excelRange = ws.Cells[cellAddress];              // Creates a range object with specified cell             
                            
        pic.ChangeCellAnchor(eEditAs.TwoCell);                      // Anchors picture to 2 cells                 
        pic.From.Column = excelRange.Start.Column-1;                // Image x1 (starting point)
        pic.From.Row = excelRange.Start.Row-1;                      // Image y1 (starting point)
        pic.From.ColumnOff = pixelsToEmu(10);                       // x1 offset (EMUs)
        pic.From.RowOff = pixelsToEmu(10);                          // y1 offset (EMUs)

        pic.To.Column = excelRange.Start.Column;                    // Image x2 (ending point)
        pic.To.Row = excelRange.Start.Row;                          // Image y2 (ending point)
        pic.To.ColumnOff = pixelsToEmu(10);                         // x2 offset (EMUs)
        pic.To.RowOff = pixelsToEmu(10);                            // y2 offset (EMUs)
            
        pic.SetSize(120,100);                                       // Sizes image

        // Other stuff ...

        package.Save();                                             // Save file with changes
    }                                                               // Ends using Excel Package            
}

And, to convert pixels to EMU units:
private static int pixelsToEmu(int pixels)
{            
    return pixels * 9525;                                           // Convert pixels to EMU units
}

I didn't find a method similar to "PlacePictureInCell" in EPPLUS, so this code was the best approximation I could make. Furthermore, I use Excel 2010, so I don't have access to richText features.

Yes this works for an "overlayed" image. Question was for an image embedded in a cell. Perhaps I should have made that more clear.

@SteveDickson, see updated code.

To give more color
Screenshot
https://i.sstatic.net/2fFfe4rM.png
if you create an "overlayed" image, the image will appear "on top of" excel cells, not imbedded in a cell in place of formulas or values.
If you unzip you will see these files (plus others)
OVERLAYED IMAGE - Unzipped xlsx
code
1. xl\media\image1.png  - Image in Media Folder

2. xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml Reference in the Worksheet XML

3. xl\drawings\_rels\sheet1.xml.rels : Relationships in the Relationships XML

4. xl\drawings\drawing1.xml  : Drawing Instructions in the Drawing XML

if you embed (as the VBA code in the original question produces) images in cells in place of formulas or values you will see this XML
IMBEDDED IMAGE Unzipped xlsx
code
1. xl\media\image1.png  - Image in Media Folder

2. xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml Reference in the Worksheet XML

3. xl\richData\rdrichvaluestructure.xml Defines relationships for rich values.

4. xl\richData\richValueRel.xml Contains metadata about the rich value types.

in particular you will see the image in the cell here rdrichvaluestructure.xml
code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rvStructures 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2017/richdata" count="1">
  <s t="_localImage">
    <k n="_rvRel:LocalImageIdentifier" t="i"/>
    <k n="CalcOrigin" t="i"/>
  </s>
</rvStructures>

